# How to Insert PHP between shortcodes for Tabs [tab]

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am looking to get some help in how to insert my php between my 2 tabs. I am using wordpress and trying to modify a template so that I can have 2 tabs on my page with dynamic content from two other php pages.

I get 2 tabs but the content does not appear in the tabs, but instead above them. I misut be doing something wrong with the code below, but I have no idea what!

My code is as follows:

```
<?php

echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed"]
[tab title="First Tab"]' .get_template_part("includes/categories-panel"). '[/tab]
[tab title="Second Tab"]'. get_template_part('includes/home-map-panel')  .'[/tab]
[tab title="Third Tab"] Tab 3 Content here [/tab]
[tab title="Fourth Tab"] Tab 4 Content here [/tab]
[/tabs]');

?>
```

any help much appreciated!

Comment: unless that get_template_part() returns `[tab]`-type text, then it's going to be like inserting bare text inside an html table structure - it'll be rendered outside of the table.

Comment: Hi Marc B, maybe that is what is happening. As the content is rendered above the tab for tab 1 & 2 above, but content 3 and 4 are fine as just text. DO u know how I would go about doing what you suggest? How to retrn `[tab]`-type text? cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_template_part` just spits out the content then and there, where the function is expecting a big long string.

You'll have to [capture the output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and put it in manually.

```
ob_start();
get_template_part("includes/categories-panel");
$cats = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
get_template_part('includes/home-map-panel');
$home = ob_get_clean();

echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed"]
[tab title="First Tab"]' .$cats. '[/tab]
[tab title="Second Tab"]'. $home  .'[/tab]
[tab title="Third Tab"] Tab 3 Content here [/tab]
[tab title="Fourth Tab"] Tab 4 Content here [/tab]
[/tabs]');
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. The issue in the OP is that wordpress functions commonly echo instead of returning. +1

Comment: Hi jeremyharris, cheers for the quick reply. I did try using your code above but now everything is outside the tabs and they look a bit messed up. Plus my google map (which is in home-map-panel) does not show the map anymore just the pins...Not sure if you were saying this is the absolute answer or just a part of the solution? thanks for any help

Comment: This is an absolute answer. It doesn't account for the fact that you are possibly calling `get_template_part` outside of the loop, which causes the template itself to break. This solves the actual question, though. The looping business and getting your template to work outside of it might be a whole other question. Also check the HTML that is outputted to make sure it's not messing with your tab HTML.

Comment: hi, thanks...yeah I must be doing something wrong. I will prob need to ask the guys at Woo to have a look at your suggestion/answer to see if they can help me out.

Comment: (pressed enter by accident) I have a code snippet here http://pastie.org/4226161 would be you able to confirm I have inserted your code correctly? cheers

Comment: Yep looks good to me. Again, if the tabs are *displaying* wrong it's probably a conflict with the template's HTML and the tab HTML. I'd look at the source to make sure it's putting in the template HTML how you want it.

Comment: Hi thanks again. As you said there must be a conflict somewhere as my tabs are now showing up on top of each other (vertical) and the tabs themselves still do not hide/show the content on the page. All is shown at once. I am not sure where to find the conflict between the tab html and the template html. Also these are tabs built into the WP theme (well the shortcode) so I would assume there would be no conflicts when using the shortcode. Thanks and hopefully I can solve this...

Comment: Again, I don't know what your tab HTML is, nor what HTML the template is spitting out, so there's no way I can really fix the new problem (which I'm certain is HTML or CSS related). You should post the HTML results as a separate question. (Feel free to leave a link to the new q here and I'll take a look.)