# Formatting HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have been trying to get my tabs working by using the tabs shortcodes in PHP.

The first part of my question was to figure out how to write the PHP code and shortcodes in the PHP file. [@jeremyharris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724063/jeremyharris) helped me out with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397441/how-to-insert-php-between-shortcodes-for-tabs-tab)

```
ob_start();
get_template_part("includes/categories-panel");
$cats = ob_get_clean();
ob_start();
get_template_part('includes/home-map-panel');
$home = ob_get_clean();

echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed"]
[tab title="First Tab"]' .$cats. '[/tab]
[tab title="Second Tab"]'. $home  .'[/tab]
[tab title="Third Tab"] Tab 3 Content here [/tab]
[tab title="Fourth Tab"] Tab 4 Content here [/tab]
[/tabs]');
```

The second question is now how to get the HTML working on the frontend. This could be a CSS or HTML conflict of some kind but the tabs are not working.

After inserting the code from the first question my HTML source looks like this http://pastie.org/4226310

I am not sure why the tabs are not showing correctly with the content. They are instead vertically aligned. I feel it might have something to do with the first include 'categories-panel' as when I remove that it works better...

I am working on localhost FYI.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are numerous validation errors when you run it through the w3c validator. Unclosed tags, blocks nested in inline elements, etc. My guess is it's an unclosed tag. Can you tell us specifically what elements are supposed to be the tabs? I can't even find "Tab 4 Content here" which should be a tab.

Comment: sorry I removed Tab 3 and 4 as I was really just adding them to see if the tabs would work correctly with plain text in them. The content that should appear in Tab 1 is the categories-panel and the tab 2 is home-maps (Sorry it was called home-map-panel above by accident) Also to note that I feel it is the categories-panel with the problem as when I remove the file reference in your code above, the second tab renders correctly- hoep that helps?

Comment: Can you update your paste? And give us an id for the categories tab element?

Comment: id=location for the categories-panel - also pastie updated - From what I can see in Firebug is that it seems to be just extending the locations to include the tabs as a location. In the hierarchy the tabs are actually within the Locations ID - mmm something must not be closing out?

Comment: Hi jeremy - I actually managed to tinker with the categories-panel.php and remove some code for it to work! The problem right now is the map in the 2nd tab does not load! only 1 tiny square of the google map loads. However, when it is in first tab it loads fine! maybe thats another question :) thanks for all your help, much appreciated!!

Comment: Yep no problem :) FYI Firebug shows what the browser interprets, which usually tries to closed unclosed tags.